# Determining whether a route falls within another route in Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, google-maps

[image]I have divided a city into number of regions using Google map's Polyline constructor.

Now I have to float a number of  routes within each region and check which have a common road map.

Let me give a example taking only 2 routes

I want to show 4 locations on Google Map: `A`, `B`, `A'` and `B'` .

`A--->B` constitutes route 1.

`A'--->B'` constitutes route 2.

Now my requirement is to check whether route 1 comes within the same route as route 2.

I have to do the same for multiple routes. But initially I want know whether it can be done in Google maps for two routes.

I followed this post 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-api/0tU9wr2eMpI and have done the same.

But this code only checks whether the route falls in straight line. It does not consider the road map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a quick and dirty example](http://jsfiddle.net/vCWFQ/3/) using google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge.

Loop through the path of the polyline's MVC array and check it against the other polyline.

```
 path.forEach(function(element, index) {
       console.log(element);    
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(element, polyline)) {
                console.log(element + " on edge");
            } else {
                console.log(element + " not on edge");
            }
    });
```

Edit: Updated the fiddle so you could see where the other line was and modified the coords a bit.